# Why does the Euclidean algorithm for finding GCD work?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I am having trouble understanding why the Euclidean algorithm for finding the GCD of two numbers always works?

I found some resources here (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Euclid.shtml), and here(http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/gs2004/euclid.html).

But I am a little confused about how they approach it here. I understand that if we have two numbers, a and b, then the greatest common divisor of a and b has to be less than a, and if a divides b, then a will have to be the GCD.

But I am confused about what happens when:

b=a*q+r
So now, we are saying that we take a/r, correct? Why should we do this at all?

Comment: Your equation should be $b=aq+r$ not ${b\over a} =aq+r$.  Does it make more sense now?

Comment: A small point is in your statement of "... the greatest common divisor of a and b has to be less than a, ...", it should be that the gcd is less than *or equal to* a instead (with this assuming $a$ is a positive integer).

Comment: @saulspatz Done! But that was not my confusion!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I will try to explain

> why the Euclidean algorithm for finding the GCD of two numbers always
>   works

by using a standard argument in number theory: showing that a problem is equivalent to the same problem for smaller numbers.

Start with two numbers $a > b \ge  0$. You want to know two things:

1. their greatest common divisor $g$,
2. and how to represent $g$ as a combination of $a$ and $b$

It's clear that you know both of these things in the easy special case when $b  = 0$.

Suppose $b > 0$. The divide $a$ by $b$ to get a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$ strictly smaller than $b$:
$$
a = bq + r. \quad \text{(*)}
$$

Now any number that divides both $a$ and $b$ also divides $r$, so divides both $b$ and $r$. Also any number that divides both $b$ and $r$ also divides $a$, so divides both $a$ and $b$. That means that the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the greatest common divisor of $b$ and $r$, so (1) has the same answer $g$ for both those pairs.

Moreover, if you can write $g$ as a combination of $b$ and $r$ then you can write it as a combination of $a$ and $b$ (substitute in (*)). That means if you can solve (2) for the pair $(b,r)$ then you can solve it for the pair $(a,b)$.

Taken together, this argument shows that you can replace your problem for $(a,b)$ by the same problem for the smaller pair $(b,r)$. Since the problem can't keep getting smaller forever, eventually you will reach $(z, 0)$ and you're done.

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please explain the statement "Now any number that divides both  and  also divides "?

Comment: @S.Dan There is not much to explain. Write $r = a - bq$, then if $a = kx$ and $b = ky$ show that $r=k \times$ something.

Answer (score 1):

Key to your question is the Well-Ordering Principle. It guarantees the existence of a least element for non-empty subsets of the natural numbers.

The GCD algorithm comes from two principles, the division algorithm and that given any two integers with a common factor, their sum and difference are both divisible by that common factor.

Suppose you have two natural numbers x and y each divisible by q. Then x=aq and y=bq for some natural numbers a and b.  x+y = q(a+b), so is divisible by q. (x-y)=q(a-b) and again is divisible by q.

The Division Algorithm guarantees given  a and b, with ab. So s must be less than b and greater than zero.

Now suppose you want to find the GCD of a and b.

By the division algorithm we know for some r and s, a=rb+s. Suppose g divides a and b. Since it divides b, it divides rb. Since it also divides a, it also divides a-rb as proven earlier. s is (a-rb) so we have proven g divides s. Why also have that s is smaller than b.

By iteration we have that b=ps+q. The division algorithm gives us p and q, with q and b having a common factor.

At each step, the remainder gets smaller and smaller.

When the remainder is zero, the previous remainder is the common factor of the original two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $\gcd(x, y) \vert (ax+by)$ for *any* linear combination of *x* and *y*, and that the smallest possible positive linear combination will always be the $\gcd$.

The Euclidean algorithm is designed to create smaller and smaller positive linear combinations of $x$ and $y$.  Since any set of positive integers has to have a smallest element, this algorithm eventually has to end.  When it does (i.e., when the next step reaches $0$), you've found your $\gcd$.