# Euclidean GCD and why does it work?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

By the dupe, the table implies $\,(14441,3565) = (3565,189) = \ldots = (28,21) = (21,7) = (7,0) = 7\ \ $

I understand that Euclid's algorithm on GCD is based on doing division via subtraction $x = qy + r$. I also understand that the process is keep expressing the quotient in terms of the remainder.
Example to find GCD of $14441$, $3563$:

| x = | q | * y | + r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14441 | 4 | 3565 | 189 |
| 3565 | 18 | 189 | 161 |
| 189 | 1 | 161 | 28 |
| 161 | 5 | 28 | 21 |
| 28 | 1 | 21 | 7 |
| 21 | 3 | 7 | 0 |

So the GCD is $7$.
So basically we try to divide the $2$ original numbers and then try to see if the remainder can express evenly $y$ and keep doing that recursively i.e. try to find the smallest number that divides the remainder.
But I am not sure I understand the intuition behind the idea. Why would that process lead to the smallest number that divides the original $x$?
I also read that a core idea is that $gcd(x,y) = gcd(y,r)$ but I didn't really get that part too.
Could someone please help?

Comment: if $d$ divides $x$ and $y$, then $d$ divides $r=x-qy$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  I know that if $d|x$ and $d|y$ then $d|(x - y)$ but I wasn't aware of what you mentioned and I am not clear how to follow the thought for the original question using that

Comment: The key idea is that, the gcd of $x$ and $y$ must also be a factor of $(x-y)$, $(x-2y)$, $\dots$, $(x-qy)=r$. As the gcd is a factor of $x$, $y$ and $r$, we can express it using any two of them.

Comment: if $d|x$ and $d|y$, then $d|x$ and $d|qy$, so $d|x-qy$

Comment: @PM2Ring: Yes that is the definition of `GCD` i.e. the greatest number that divides both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @PM2Ring: That was bad phrasing from my side. It is the smallest number reached from that set of divisions but somehow it is the greatest divider

Comment: @PM2Ring: None of the decreasing numbers besides $7$ is a divisor of $14441$ though. So how do they retain the factors along the process exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119564/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-jim).

Comment: @PM2Ring: Replied there, I am sorry just saw your message

Comment: By the dupe, the table implies $\,(14441,3565) = (3565,189) = \ldots = (28,21) = (21,7) = (7,0) = 7,\,$ where we use the common notation $\,(x,y):=\gcd(x,y)\ \ $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379695/why-does-the-euclidean-algorithm-for-finding-gcd-work/3379763#3379763

Comment: Since the remainder sequence is strictly decreasing it must eventually reach $0\,$ (by $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered), so the last nonzero remainder (here $7)$ is the gcd.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to consider just a single step:

For any two numbers $x$ and $y$ with $y<x$, consider $x$ and $x-y$.

Any divisor of $x$ and $y$ is also a divisor of $x-y$ and $y$. Similarly, any divisor of $x-y$ and $y$ is also  a divisor of $x$ and $y$. Thus gcd$(x,y)=$ gcd$(x-y,y)$.

We have thus reduced the pair of numbers and can repeat this over and over again.

Comment: @Jim I would add to S. Dolan's answer that if you examine the chart in your query, you will notice two attributes that will **always** be present, regardless of the initial values of $x$ and $y$ : [1] The numbers in the left hand column are **strictly decreasing** [2] The *bottom row* of the chart will **always** have $r = 0.$

Comment: @S. Dolan: "Thus $gcd(,)= gcd(−,)$" and where does $r$ come in the picture?

Comment: If x-y>y then the next step would be x-2y and y . Repeating this as necessary you get x-qy=r.

Comment: It seems to me that your answer more focuses on the algorithm, but I still don't get the intuitive idea behind it. I do understand the process

Comment: gcd$(x,y)=$ gcd$(x-y,y)$ looks like an intuitive idea to me.

Comment: @S.Dolan:So if we have two numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x > y$ we try to see if $y$ divides $x$ evenly. If so then $y$ is the gcd. This is intuitively understood. Now if it does not evenly divide it means we get a remainder $r>0$. I also can intuitively understand that we now can turn our attention to $r$ since if we find that $r$ evenly divides $y$ it is evenly divides $x$ but it is not clear to me at a high level why can't there be some other factor e.g. $z$ inside $y$ where $y>r$ that divides both $x$ and $y$ evenly? Or the intuition is only part of going over the algebraic equalities?

Comment: $r$ is $x$  minus a multiple of  $y$. It would therefore be a multiple of your $z$.