# How to quickly identify common factors

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

What's a good approach for identifying potentially large common factors?

For example, how do I quickly recognise that 123543/99900 is reducible to 371/300?

Or putting this another way, how do I efficiently work out that 123543 and 99900 have the common factor 333?

Comment: Do you know about the Euclidean algorithm? Check it out in wikipedia. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379695/why-does-the-euclidean-algorithm-for-finding-gcd-work/3379763#3379763

Comment: Short answer: learn small divisibility rules.

Comment: Test each number as a factor which is smaller than its square root. Also, context and your attempts at the problem are well. You may read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), even though you received the cross account reputation bonus.

Comment: @SeanRoberson That won't help much with big numbers. And the OP wants the greatest common factor, not all the factors.

Comment: @TymaGaidash  That won't help much with big numbers. And the OP wants the greatest common factor, not all the factors.